# Generate new Date series based on common dates from two date series

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to compare two data series with dates and on a third column show ONLY the dates that are common in both data series (ordered in descending mode).  A friend of mine helped me put together some code that seems to work but it seems to be taking a long time to generate the result when I have quite a long series of data.  Is there a way to write this code differently that might get calculated faster? (I am currently using excel 2010.

The Function I enter on D2 and then I copy it down is: `=next_duplicate(A2:$A$535,B2:$B$535,D1:$D$1)`

[image]

```
Function next_duplicate(list1, list2, excluded)
   For Each c In list1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(excluded, c) = 0 Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(list2, c) > 0 Then
            next_duplicate = c
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next c

If next_duplicate = 0 Then
    next_duplicate = "N/A"
End If
End Function
```

Comment: can duplicate values exist within one column? like can column A contain more than 1 of the same date? Or how about a **Non-VBA** solution. Run this formula against the column with more dates *(right now run against column A in your example)* `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$6,1,FALSE)),"","Common")`. It will give you the dates that exist on the other column, than you can filter or sort or whatever to grab the common ones.

Comment: Hi Scott,
no there are no duplicate dates on Dates_1 or Dates_2. The issue is that I would like to get the final list in sort of an automated way (ie. function) so that there is not a lot of extra sorting/steps to get the list...

Comment: It's only 3 steps! **1)** write the formula **2)** auto-fill it down **3)** sort (or filter)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without VBA.

In Column C use COUNTIF to extract dates that appear only in both Columns A and B

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,"="&A2) > 0, A2, 0)
```

Then in Column D use an array formula (from [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/06/sorting-numbers-and-text-cells-also-removing-blanks-using-array-formula-in-excel/)) to sort and remove blanks. Don't forget to select the range and then press control, shift and enter.

```
=INDEX(C2:C7, MATCH(LARGE(IF(ISBLANK(C2:C7), "", IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C7), COUNTIF(C2:C7, "<"&C2:C7), COUNTIF(C2:C7, "<"&C2:C7)+SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C7), 1, 0))+1)), ROW()-ROW($D$2)+1), IF(ISBLANK(C2:C7), "", IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C7), COUNTIF(C2:C7, "<"&C2:C7), COUNTIF(C2:C7, "<"&C2:C7)+SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C7), 1, 0))+1)), 0))
```

Comment: Thank you Dan for this, I notice this sorts the final "Common_Dates" list ascending. is there a way to get it descending order? (I tried changing SMALL by LARGE but I get the blanks on top (and I wouldn't like them there)).

Comment: I can't find it now but I did once point someone to the same link and I believe they said they just flipped all the < to > to change the order. Give that a try. Although this one removes blanks so I'm not sure how that behaviour will be affected.

Comment: Actually if you have a look at the link I sent, the next article in the series does it descending: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/06/sorting-numbers-and-text-cells-descending-also-removing-blanks-using-array-formula-in-excel/

Comment: yes, I saw that link yesterday but as Column "C" does have cells with "" data in them (instead of blank or empty cell) they show up on top (if you see what I mean)

Comment: I see, ok so I have changed it to be 0 instead of "", this does the ordering correctly but puts 00-Jan in the cells at the bottom that should be blank. You could sort this out with an IF(entire array formula = 0, entire array formula, "") and as 0 is not a real date you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If @Dan's solution works, go with that since formula solutions are usually cooler :) If you need to use VBA, you can try this:

```
Sub Common()

Dim Date1 As Range
Dim Date2 As Range
Dim CommonDates() As Variant
Dim UniqueDates As New Collection

Set Date1 = Range("A2:A6")
Set Date2 = Range("B2:B6")

' Change the max array size to equal the length of Date1
' This is arbitrary and could be more efficient, for sure :)
ReDim CommonDates(Date1.Count)

' Set a counter that will increment with matches
i = 0

' Since a match needs to be in both, iterate through Date1 and check
' if the Match function returns a True value when checking Date2.
' If so, add that value to the CommonDates array and increment the counter.
For Each DateVal In Date1
  If IsError(Application.Match(DateVal, Date2, 0)) = False Then
    CommonDates(i) = DateVal.Value
    i = i + 1
  End If
Next

' Filter out dupes (in case that is possible - if not, this can be removed
' and the bottom part reworked
On Error Resume Next
For Each Value In CommonDates
  UniqueDates.Add Value, CStr(Value)
Next Value

' Now go to the first cell in your Common Dates range (I'm using C2) and
' print out all of the results
Range("C2").Activate
For j = 1 To UniqueDates.Count
  ActiveCell.Value = UniqueDates(j)
  ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate
Next j

' Back to the beginning
Range("C2").Activate

' Use this if you don't need to filter dupes
'For Each r In CommonDates
'  ActiveCell.Value = r
'  ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate
'Next

End Sub
```

It basically iterates over Date1 and checks if the Match formula succeeds/fails in Date2. A success = match, which means a common date. Those are then printed to another column. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you RocketDonkey, as the data that is going to be coming is dynamic, ideally I am looking for a function rather than a macro to deal with the data... The Function I have at the moment just seems to take way too long to calculate and create the final list so I am curious as to whether there is something faster out there.

Comment: Ah, gotcha - go for @Dan's solution then. This solution would (hopefully) avoid the overhead of recalculating the formula every time the sheet is updated (which can drag performance down, especially with COUNTIFs). I believe the reason your original code is a bit slow is that it is running a COUNTIF WorksheetFunction on everything. I haven't tried out Dan's, but I'll always support a formula-over-VBA approach if it works the same :)